# React -- refer to an instance of the encapsulated object?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Relatively new to React. I have the following components:

```
var Vertex = React.createClass({

    //2. I want to parameterize this instantiation, however i cannot use this.props inside my render function's <ref> tag, as it gives me parsing errors

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div ref={createVertex()}>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

var Cloud = React.createClass({

    statics: {
        push: function(points){
          points.forEach(function(point){
           // 1. I want to do a this.push.vertices(point)
        });
      }
    },

    render: function() {
      return (

        <div ref={createCloud()}>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

function createVertex(){
    return new THREE.Vector3();
};

function createCloud(){
    return new THREE.Geometry();
};
```

Questions:

1. The object that is returned by createCloud() is encapsulated in my React component. How should I refer to an instance of that object as mentioned in comment 1. above?
2. Separately, I am unable to use this.props inside the render function's  tag. What is the correct way to parameterize the instantiation of the object here as mentioned in comment 2. above?

**Edit 1: adding details of intended usage (not working). I'm trying to create a constellation (THREE.PointCloud) with stars (THREE.Vector3) as it's vertices**

```
  var options = {
    x: <some val>,
    y: <some val>,
    z: <some val>
  };

  var star = React.createElement(Vertex, options); //Relevant to problem faced in comment 2.

  var stars = [];
  stars.push(star);

  Cloud.push(stars); //Relevant to problem faced in comment 1.

  var constellation = React.createElement(Cloud);
```

Comment: We need a bit more detail on what you're trying to accomplish here. What it sounds like is you want to create a new `THREE.Geometry` when your `Cloud` component is created, keep an internal reference to the geometry within the component, and be able to call the `push` function to add vertices to the geometry? From where will `push` be called? Why are you using `statics` and `ref`?

Comment: @JCD Thanks and you're correct. Added details of intended usage to question, as Edit 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish by using React to manage THREE.js objects, but I'll try to answer your two questions.

> The object that is returned by createCloud() is encapsulated in my
>   React component. How should I refer to an instance of that object as
>   mentioned in comment 1. above?

The short answer is... you can't.

The reason why is that by definition, functions defined in React's `static` object can't access component state or props, because state and props *don't exist yet*. "Static" functions are designed to be called on the *class itself* and not *instances of the class*. So assuming your `this.push.vertices(point)` is supposed to act on a `THREE.Geometry` object, that's impossible to do, because that geometry would have to live in the component's state.

Instead what you probably want to do is declare a function in the class but outside of the `static` object. That function would take some kind of input and use `setState()` to change the internal state of the React component. Remember that React component state is supposed to be immutable which means that it should never be set directly. Always mutate data separately and then use `setState()` to update it. So for example if you had a THREE.Geometry held in a component's state that you wanted to change, you would clone the geometry, update the clone, and then use `setState` to update the component state with the *new* geometry.

(Side note: it's a bad idea to call external functions that are defined outside of a React class, unless you've explicitly imported them into the class as part of a module or something. Define stuff like `createVertex` and `createCloud` inside of the classes that use them.)

> Separately, I am unable to use this.props inside the render function's
>   tag. What is the correct way to parameterize the instantiation of the
>   object here as mentioned in comment 2. above?

Using props is exactly how you would "parameterize" a new instance of a React component. I think you're just overcomplicating things.

Remember that props get passed to a component by its parent (or instantiation) while state is used to manage internal state *after* it has been created. When a component is created, one of the first things that happens is the built-in function `getInitialState` is called, at which point the component has access to its props, so that it can use them to initialize its own state. So if you want a React component that creates its own internal state based on the props (essentially, "parameters") that are passed to it, it would look something like this:

1. Parent instantiates a new React component with props
2. The new component uses `getInitialState` to parse the props and use it to create an initial state
3. Later on, use `setState()` to update the component's state

Like this maybe:

```
var Cloud = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        // do something with this.props,
        // for example you could use the props to create a new THREE.Geometry,
        // then return the initial state to include the new Geometry
        this.props.arrayOfVertices.forEach(...);
        ...
        // make some geometry
        ...
        return {geometry: myNewGeometry};
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
});

var myCloud = React.createComponent(Cloud, {arrayOfVertices: [...]});
```

I hope that somewhat answers your questions. But if you're new to React, I would steer clear of using it to drive a THREE.js app. React is designed to render a DOM, and unless you're very comfortable using it for that purpose, you're going to have a *miserable* time adapting it to THREE.js right off the bat. In order to do so you would need a masterful understanding of the React component lifecycle, which from what I see here you do not yet have. Play around with React a bit on its own, get your sea legs under you, and keep things simple!

Comment: This is great ! Thanks for the effort in explaining !